# Python list recursive changes

Tags: python, list, recursion, return, tail-recursion

I have a bug in my attempt to add to a list a sequence of numbers recursively. E.g. if the input is [5,3,9], I do [5+1,3+2,9+3] and output [6,5,12]. I want to do this recursively so the way I'm doing it is going through and adding one to a smaller and smaller part of the list as below:

```
def add_position_recur(lst, number_from=0):
    length = len(lst)
    # base case
    if (length <= 1):
        lst = [x+1 for x in lst]
        print "last is", lst
    else:
        lst = [x+1 for x in lst]
        print "current list is", lst
        add_position_recur(lst[1:], number_from)
        return lst
```

The problem, though, is that all this does is add 1 to every element of the list. Where is the bug? Is it to do with the way I return the list in the base case?

Comment: what is `number_from` used for? it has zero use in your code. And be aware that you are changing your `lst` to reference a new list when you do `lst = ...`. It doesn't change the original list passed in as the argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you recurse down your call stack you slice `lst` which creates a new list, this is not the same as what you return, so you will only ever return the changes you've applied to your list in the first call to the function, losing all changes further down the stack:

```
>>> add_position_recur([1,2,3])
[2, 3, 4]
```

This should have returned `[2, 4, 6]`.
You need to consider reassembling the list on the way out to get the changes.

```
return [lst[0]] + add_position_recur(lst[1:], number_from)
```

and you need to `return lst` in your base case:

```
def add_position_recur(lst, number_from=0):
    length = len(lst)
    # base case
    if (length <= 1):
        lst = [x+1 for x in lst]
        return lst
    else:
        lst = [x+1 for x in lst]
        return [lst[0]] + add_position_recur(lst[1:], number_from)
>>> add_position_recur([1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
```

However, this is quite a complicated approach to this recursion. It is idiomatic for the base case to be the empty list, otherwise take the head and recurse down the tail. So something to consider which uses the `number_from`:

```
def add_position_recur(lst, number_from=1):
    if not lst:
        return lst
    return [lst[0]+number_from] + add_position_recur(lst[1:], number_from+1)

>>> add_position_recur([1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
```

This also has the advantage(?) of not changing the passed in `lst`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you instead do something like this:

```
def func(lon, after=[]):
    if not l:
        pass
    else:
        v = len(lon) + lon[-1]
        after.append(v)
        func(lon[:-1], after)
        return after[::-1]
```

The output of the function for the example you provided matches what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are simply adding 1 to each value of your list.

```
lst = [x+1 for x in lst]
```

Rather, you should be increasing a variable which is being added to x with each iteration of x in lst.

```
lst = [x+(lst.index(x)+1) for x in lst]
```

This solution assumes that you want the number being added to x to depend on its position in the list relative to the start of the list, rather than being dependent on the position of x relative to the first element which was >1. Meaning, do you want to add 1 or 3 to the value 2 in the following list? The solution above adds three.

```
lst = [0.5, 0.1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Don't do `[x+(lst.index(x)+1) for x in lst]`, it won't work when there are duplicate items and it is also really slow. Use `enumerate`: `[x+(i+1) for i,x in enumerate(lst)]`.

Comment: @DanD. even better, use the `start` argument to `enumerate` to avoid the extra arithmetic: `[x+i for i,x in enumerate(lst, start=1)]`.